# Assembler .weak directive does only work with Cross Compile GCC

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, linker, weak-references

I have a program which I compile with 2 different compilers:

**GCC 3.4.4 Cross Compiler for PowerPC**

**GCC 4.8.1 MinGW Compiler**

In the program I am using the assembler directive `.weak` . The documentation says:

`Makes a symbol with weak binding globally visible to the linker.`

So I am going like this:

```
__asm__(".weak " "foo" "\n.set " "foo" "," "dummy_foo" "\n");
```

To cleare `foo` weak and give it an alias to `dummy_foo`.

This code works fine under GCC 3.4.4 when I cross compile für PowerPC but it doesn't work with GCC 4.8.1 when I compile for x86 target. - The Code compiles, but `foo` is not declared `weak` and my linker gives me an undefined reference. What is the problem here?

**//edit:**

As BSH suggested, it has to be:

```
__asm__(".weak " "_foo" "\n.set " "_foo" "," "_dummy_foo" "\n");
```

If I put this line into the same C-File as my declaration of `foo()` it works fine. The problem still persists when I put it in a seperate C-File (then it works for the GCC 3.4.4 Cross Compiler, but not for the GCC 4.8.1 )

Answer (score 1):

In MinGW, symbols are prefixed with an underscore, `_foo`, you need to change it to:

```
__asm__(".weak " "_foo" "\n.set " "_foo" "," "_dummy_foo" "\n");
```

or consider using the [attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) `__attribute__((weak, alias("dummy_foo")))` with `foo` instead.

Comment: Ok, I was missing the thing with the preceding _ for MinGW - unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem. If I place the `__asm__` directive in the same file as the declaration of `foo()` it works - but when I put the `__asm__` directive in a seperate C-File it only works for the GCC 3.4.4 Cross Compiler and not for my GCC 4.8.1 . This is also the reason why I don't use `attribute`, since I want to declare the function as `weak` in another C-File.