# Is implementing weak linkage using variable declaration/definition portable?

Tags: c

I recently learned that:

```
int a;
```

at file scope is a variable declaration and by default has external linkage.
So I can use this to implement something like weak symbol/function linkage:

```
cat >lib.c <<'EOF'
#include "lib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// This is declaration
// It will be initialized to NULL in case no definition is found
void (* const lib_callback_pnt)(int);

void lib_callback_default(int a) 
{
   printf("%s %d\n", __func__, a);
}

void lib_call(int a)
{
   printf("%s calling %p\n", __func__, 
    // this is not really portable
    (void*)(uintptr_t)(intmax_t)lib_callback_pnt
   );
   // call callback
   void (* const lib_callback_to_call)(int) = 
      lib_callback_pnt == NULL
      ? lib_callback_default
      : lib_callback_pnt;
   lib_callback_to_call(a);
}

EOF
```

```
cat >lib.h <<'EOF'
#ifndef LIB_H_
#define LIB_H_

extern void (* const lib_callback_pnt)(int);

void lib_callback_default(int a);
void lib_call(int a);

#endif
EOF
```

```
cat >main1.c <<EOF
#include "lib.h"

int main() {
    lib_call(42);
}

EOF
```

```
cat >main2.c <<'EOF'
#include "lib.h"
#include <stdio.h>

static void my_lib_callback(int a)
{
    printf("Hah! Overwritten lib callback!\n");
}

// this is definition
void (* const lib_callback_pnt)(int) = my_lib_callback;

int main() {
    lib_call(42);
}

EOF
```

```
cat >Makefile <<'EOF'
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11
all:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) lib.c main1.c -o main1
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) lib.c main2.c -o main2
EOF
```

Inside `lib.c` library I declare a function pointer `void (* const lib_callback_pnt)(int)`, which serves as a callback. The function pointer is not initialized in `lib.c` and will be default initialized to NULL (cause static storage duration).

Then I have two programs or user applications, that is  `main1.c` and `main2.c`.

The `main1.c` simply calls library function which calls the callback - the callback is nowhere initialized, so it is default initialized to NULL - I can compare that inside library and call the default callback / choose action appropriately.

The `main2.c` however declares the function pointer `lib_callback_pnt` with initialization - it is a definition. There is a single definition of this variable in all source files, so the linker does not complain about multiple symbol definitions. When we call the library, the pointer is initialized, thus the user application `main2` has successfully overwritten the callback.

We can compile:

```
$ make
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11 lib.c main1.c -o main1
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11 lib.c main2.c -o main2
```

And call:

```
$ ./main1 
lib_call calling (nil)
lib_callback_default 42
$ ./main2 
lib_call calling 0x5627c07871cf
Hah! overwritten lib callback!
```

Questions:

- Is this portable? Is this conforming to C standard?
- Are there any / Which libraries use such method to enable user application to pass user defined callbacks and/or parameters? Why isn't such method used that often?

Comment: AFAIK there is no portable way to obtain weak references. Most implementations I've seen, uses the assembler + the linker to achieve this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765335/assembler-weak-directive-does-only-work-with-cross-compile-gcc

Comment: @AlexF: The question is not whether the code shown in the question contains a weak linkage as usually implemented by compiler extensions and/or linkers. The question is whether the code in the question serves, by way of relying on default initialization of a pointer with external linkage, as a method of implement its own weak linkage.

Comment: Yes. In "runtime" (may be optimized) and prior to main function. From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol#Use_cases): `Weak symbols can be used as a mechanism to provide default implementations of functions that can be replaced by more specialized (e.g. optimized) ones at link-time.`. I want the same functionality, but without using the weak attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `lib.c`, `void (* const lib_callback_pnt)(int);` is a declaration of an identifier for an object (in this case, a pointer) that has file scope without an initializer and without a storage-class specifier. Then C 2018 6.9.2 2 tells us:

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier **static**, constitutes a *tentative definition*. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative definitions for an identifier, and the translation unit contains no external definition for that identifier, then the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer equal to 0.

This tells us that in standard C, `lib_callback_pnt` is initialized to zero even if it is defined in a different translation unit. And the fact that it behaves as if it had an initializer means it is defined in `lib.c`.

Furthermore, when `lib_callback_pnt` is defined in `main2.c`, this violates C 2018 6.9 5:

> If an identifier declared with external linkage is used in an expression (other than as part of the operand of a **sizeof** or **_Alignof** operator whose result is an integer constant), somewhere in the entire program there shall be exactly one external definition for the identifier; otherwise, there shall be no more than one.

## Note

There is some tradition in Unix of permitting the declaration of `int foo;` in one translation unit and `int foo = 1;` in another. Technically, this is not defined by the C standard, but it may be commonly available in compilers and linkers.

Comment: It's a well-established convention of traditional unix linking rules, not something allowed by C.

Comment: @R..: It is just convention and tradition, or is there documentation?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's documented in the ELF/SYSV gABI documents. It's clearly the motivation for why commons exist in object files as opposed to just getting converted to bss at assembly time.

Answer (score 2):

Your lib.c actually does define `lib_callback_pnt`.  C11 says at [6.9.2p2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.2p2):

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier `static`, constitutes a *tentative definition*. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative definitions for an identifier, and the translation unit contains no external definition for that identifier, then the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer equal to 0.

So the declaration of `lib_callback_pnt` in lib.c is a tentative definition. Since that translation unit doesn't contain any other declaration of `lib_callback_pnt` that explicitly defines it, the behavior should be the same as a true definition that initializes it with "`= 0`".

Apparently gcc with ELF output doesn't follow this requirement exactly by default.
 On my Linux system, if I `gcc -c lib.c; nm lib.o | grep lib_callback_pnt`, I get:

```
0000000000000008 C lib_callback_pnt
```

And my `man nm` documentation explains "C" means a "common symbol":

> "C" The symbol is common.  Common symbols are uninitialized data.  When linking, multiple common symbols may appear with the same name.  If the symbol is defined anywhere, the common symbols are treated as undefined references.

So your method does work with gcc/ELF, but it's incorrect according to the C Standard, so you can't count on it to work with other compilers.

Comment: Notably, declaring a file scope variable without `static`, but with internal linkage, is an obsolete language feature (C17 6.11.2). This feature may be removed from the C language and we shouldn't write code like that.

Comment: @Lundin `lib_callback_pnt` has external linkage. C does not have the C++ rule that "`const` implies `static`", and the first declaration is actually marked `extern` via lib.h in each translation unit.

Comment: It may not apply in this case, just saying that it is good practice to use either `static` or `extern`. (Although using `extern` is in itself often bad practice because it leads to spaghetti coding with globals.)